# SendMail Help in VB

Tags: vb.net, sendmail

I developed a sendmail program for support which works great.  What I am trying to do now is add a history page, which will show my users what support requests they have sent previously.  I plan on use My.Settings to save the each email sent from my program.

Here is my code for the SendMail button which sends me mail:

```
 If TextBox1.Text = "" Then
                MsgBox("Please describe the issue you're having Bender, I'm not a mindreader!")
                Exit Sub
            Else
                lblpleasewait.Visible = True
                delay(2000)
                Dim Recipients As New List(Of String)
                Recipients.Add("johndoe@yahoo.com")
                Dim FromEmailAddress As String = Recipients(0)
                Dim Subject As String = "IT Help!"
                Dim Body As String = TextBox1.Text
                Dim UserName As String = My.Settings.txtboxUN
                Dim Password As String = My.Settings.txtboxPW
                Dim Port As Integer = My.Settings.txtboxSMTPPort
                Dim Server As String = My.Settings.txtboxSMTP
                Dim Attachments As New List(Of String)
                MsgBox(SendEmail(Recipients, FromEmailAddress, Subject, Body, UserName, Password, Server, Port, Attachments))
                lblpleasewait.Visible = False
                TextBox1.Text = ""
                TextBox1.Focus()
'This is where the beginning of my code is to send it to the history form.
                Dim str(2) As String
                Dim itm As ListViewItem
                str(0) = Today + " - " + TimeOfDay
                str(1) = Body
                itm = New ListViewItem(str)
                GTSMailHistory.ListView1.Items.Add(itm)
                My.Settings.logDate = str(0)
                My.Settings.logIssue = str(1)
                My.Settings.Save()
            End If
```

As you can from the above code, the last few lines is where I add the Body of the email and the time of day and add it to my listview I have on another form (GTSMailHistory).

My problem is this, that code above sending it over to the other form is saving, but is overwritten with each new email.  Its basically not appending new emails to the list, just writing over the first.

The only code I have on the history form is on the LOAD function which is below:

```
Private Sub GTSMailHistory_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
        Dim str(2) As String
        Dim itm As ListViewItem
        str(0) = My.Settings.logDate
        str(1) = My.Settings.logIssue
        itm = New ListViewItem(str)
        ListView1.Items.Add(itm)

    End Sub
```

Comment: Are you recreating your `GTSMailHistory` object each pass instead of just once at startup?

Comment: When saving the date/body to `My.Settings` you are overwriting the existing values. Don't you want these to be lists instead?

Comment: Joiner, i do want it to be a list.  Can i save a listview to my.settings so it remains persistent upon next program launch?  I dont want to create a separate external database/textfile, i want the history to be local to the compiled program.

Answer (score 0):

I can't leave comments yet so if someone could move this it'd help.

Are you recreating your GTSMailHistory object each pass instead of just once at startup?

Also when saving the date/body to My.Settings you are overwriting the existing values, do you not want these to be lists instead?

In response to your comment:

> Joiner, i do want it to be a list. Can i save a listview to my.settings so it remains persistent upon next program launch?

You can use My.Settings to store variables of different types including lists.

In Visual Studio go to:

Project -> Properties -> Settings (Tab) -> Add a setting and its type (browse for more).

See [here](http://www.dreamincode.net/forums/topic/72654-using-settings/) for an example.

Comment: I think im getting closer.  I wrote the below LOAD code but its only saving in Column 1(Date) and not moving on to Column2(issue).
Dim x As System.Configuration.SettingsProperty

        For Each x In My.Settings.Properties
            Me.ListView1.Items.Add(My.Settings.logDate)
            Me.ListView1.Items.Add(My.Settings.logIssue)
        Next

How to i tell the above that logDate is Column 1 in the listview and logIssue is column 2 in the listview?

Comment: You should remove the comments suggesteds part.

Answer (score 0):

Found sort of an answer.  Not really want i want but will suffice right now.  I can write this to a textfile and use streamreader to load it to listview.

The below code adds the body and date to listview:

```
Static i As Integer = 0
        Dim newItem As New ListViewItem(Today + " - " + TimeOfDay) '// add text Item.
        newItem.SubItems.Add(TextBox2.Text) '// add SubItem.
        history.ListView1.Items.Add(newItem) '// add Item to ListView.
        i += 1
```

The below code loads the saved textfile

```
ListView1.View = View.Details : ListView1.Columns.Add("Date") : ListView1.Columns.Add("Issue")
        If IO.File.Exists(myCoolFile) Then '// check if file exists.
            Dim myCoolFileLines() As String = IO.File.ReadAllLines(myCoolFile) '// load your file as a string array.
            For Each line As String In myCoolFileLines '// loop thru array list.
                Dim lineArray() As String = line.Split("#") '// separate by "#" character.
                Dim newItem As New ListViewItem(lineArray(0)) '// add text Item.
                newItem.SubItems.Add(lineArray(1)) '// add SubItem.
                ListView1.Items.Add(newItem) '// add Item to ListView.
            Next
        End If
```

On form close it saves my entries:

```
Dim myWriter As New IO.StreamWriter(myCoolFile)
        For Each myItem As ListViewItem In ListView1.Items
            myWriter.WriteLine(myItem.Text & "#" & myItem.SubItems(1).Text) '// write Item and SubItem.
        Next
        myWriter.Close()
```